# Upgrade to 14.04 broke gsettings

Tags: 14.04, dconf, gsettings

I have a cron job which runs every 30 minutes that changes the background image by running this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0
export GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf

wpdir="/home/username/Pictures/wallpapers/"
prefix="file://"
file=`ls $wpdir | shuf -n 1`
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$prefix$wpdir$file"
```

This worked perfectly until I upgraded to 14.04. Now, running the script produces this output:

```
(process:27459): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

What can I do to fix this? Google didn't turn up any useful results.

EDIT: I noticed that running this does change the background displayed on the lock screen, but it does not affect the desktop background.